# Error while installing react native picker

Tags: react-native, npm, picker

I upgraded **react-native** version to "**0.68.2**" and **native-base** version to "**^3.2.1**". Then I have a problem on Android app.

Android app show Warning: Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker

while installing this library I faced errors and it doesn't installed :

```
npm install @react-native-picker/picker --save
```

The error is as following:

> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving:
> undefined@undefined npm WARN Found: react-native@0.68.1 npm WARN
> node_modules/react-native npm WARN   peer react-native@"> 0.57" from
> @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome@0.2.7 npm WARN
> node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome npm WARN
> @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome@"^0.2.7" from the root project
> npm WARN   49 more (@miblanchard/react-native-slider, ...) npm WARN
> npm WARN Could not resolve dependency: npm WARN peer
> react-native@"^0.56.0" from react-native-cardview@2.0.5 npm WARN
> node_modules/react-native-cardview npm WARN
> react-native-cardview@"^2.0.5" from the root project npm ERR! code
> ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! npm ERR! While
> resolving: react-native-elements@3.4.2 npm ERR! Found:
> react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4 npm ERR! node_modules/react-nati

Comment: Do `npm install @react-native-picker/picker --legacy-peer-deps` which allows you to install peer dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried expo install @react-native-picker/picker & that's work